# What file types does GitHub support for README's

Tags: github, file-type, readme

I have noticed that many different file types are used for GitHub READMEs. The most common ones are `.md` and `.rst`

After looking at the GitHub documentation and the help page I found no information on which file types are allowed.

I am just looking for a list of the types so I can figure out which types I can use for my next README.

Comment: I found it supports no file extension and also .html

Comment: @HaydenThring Yes, the Markdown renderer appears to be quite flexible, but I don't believe that mixing HTML in with Markdown is recommended as per the 'Markdown Style Guide' if there is such a thing.

Comment: I was a bit quick to post, as while it will display it, i cant seem to get it to interpret the html codes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GitHub uses its own [Markup library](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md#markups) to render files like READMEs. It supports:

- [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (.markdown, .mdown, .mkdn, .md)
- [Textile](https://textile-lang.com/) (.textile)
- [RDoc](https://ruby.github.io/rdoc/) (.rdoc)
- [Org](http://orgmode.org/) (.org)
- [Creole](http://wikicreole.org/) (.creole)
- [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting) (.mediawiki, .wiki)
- [Restructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) (.rst)
- [AsciiDoc](http://asciidoc.org/) (.asciidoc, .adoc, .asc)
- [Perl Pod](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlpod.pod) (.pod)

Comment: Those are each variations of Markup?

Comment: I am asking more of what file types such a .txt, .md, etc.

Comment: @WilliamV: If you follow the [Markup library](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md#markups) link in the answer, it shows the file extensions and links to more information about each format.