# Insert inline images in README.md

Tags: image, github, svg, readme

Is it possible to insert an inline image (base64 encoded) via HTML or Markdown in README.md (GitHub)?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render inline images in a file that isn't the `README` (which github requires be a [certain set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112364/239657) of extensions) - Github does, for example, render inline base64 images in markdown cells of Jupyter notebooks.

So, you can create a Jupyter notebook (`.ipynb`) with a single markdown cell that contains all of the markdown.

Comment: README can render [many formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112364/239657), e.g. .rst, .adoc etc. but indeed no README.ipynb

Answer (score -3):

Such a possibility exists:

```
![image](data:image/png;base64,<BASE64_HERE>)
```

But I would rather add an image to the project, similar to the README.MD itself, and only refer to the image that is part of the project.

More info: https://github.com/YourUserAccount/YourProject/blob/master/DirectoryPath/ReadMe.md

Comment: Github renders it as: `<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href=""><img alt="image" style="max-width: 100%;"></a>`

Comment: In addition - this would probably never ever be implemented. 
https://github.com/github/markup/issues/270