# How to change file for Github pages?

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-pages

i need a little help...
Actually i have made a GitHub page but i want to change the file which is being displayed to the website made by me ...
Actually it's a .md file and i made a html file...

Now i want to change the file which is being displayed in the site.
I want to switch from .md to html file which is already in my repo for GitHub pages.

If anyone knows how to deal with it, please help

I'm also adding my github repo link : https://github.com/S2Sofficial/swaroop2sky

And here is the github page link:
https://s2sofficial.github.io/swaroop2sky/

Answer (score 0):

Create `index.html` file, and it will work as your home page.

**OR**
simply, change the file name of `Welcome to Swaroop2sky _ swaroop2sky.html`  to `index.html`.

Comment: Glad, that helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You can not show your website on GitHub page.

You can include [html tags in README](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) to format text.

GitHub does not support html format for README. See [answer on StackOverflow about README formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112364/16236820).

GitHub does not support [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) either. See [answer on SO about iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54613247/16236820).